# JQuery Datepicker - no default date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I want to remove the default date in my JQuery Datepicker.

I try the following code:

```
$(this).datepicker({defaultDate: ''});
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Today's date is still selected as default.

Answer (score 11):

I got round the problem using a hidden altField:

```
<div id="DatePicker"></div>
<input type="hidden" value="" name="Date" id="Date" />
```

and the following script:

```
<script>
    $(function () {

        $('#DatePicker').datepicker({
            altField: '#Date', // ID of the hidden field
            altFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
        });

        // Remove the style for the default selected day (today)
        $('.ui-datepicker-current-day').removeClass('ui-datepicker-current-day');

        // Reset the current selected day
        $('#Date').val('');
    });
</script>
```

Then, I used the hidden #Date field in my validation routines.

Comment: I had better results by removing the `ui-state-active` and `ui-state-hover` from the child element.

`$('.ui-datepicker-current-day .ui-state-active').removeClass('ui-state-active').removeClass('ui-state-hover');`

Possibly due to version changes

Comment: It would be soooo awesome if we could set the date value for altField, within onClose, if the input field is empty.  Just dreaming beyond the original question...

Answer (score 10):

None of the answers at the time of this writing really worked for me, so here was my solution cobbled from a couple of answers (for an inline datepicker).

```
    $('.calendar').datepicker("setDate", null); // this unsets the datepicker's internal selected date; it still shows a highlight on today's date that looks like a selected date though
    $('.calendar').find(".ui-datepicker-current-day").removeClass("ui-datepicker-current-day"); // this actually removes the highlight
```

Comment: This worker for me instead of the 2nd line:  `$('.calendar').find(".ui-datepicker-current-day a ").removeClass("ui-state-highlight ui-state-active");`

Answer (score 7):

This is actually an open issue with *jQuery UI Datepicker*. Here is the ticket for the issue:

[Ticket 8159](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8159)

At the heart of this issue is the fact that *Datepicker* incorrectly handles a *defaultDate* value of *null*. Of the solutions offered here, I like that of [j-polfer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40411/j-polfer) the best and upvoted it for that reason. The reason this solution works, though, is because there is a patch built into the *setDate* method to clear the selection if *null* is passed into the date parameter. But I wanted to find out *why* the Datepicker was not responding correctly to the *defaultDate:null* in the options, and so I took a look at the source.

I found that I needed to make three changes to the *Datepicker* source code to fix this issue. Here are the changes that I made:

1. The method *_getDefaultDate* returned the current date when *defaultDate* option was null or missing (This is the heart of the problem).

I changed this method from this...

```
    _getDefaultDate: function(inst) {
        return this._restrictMinMax(inst,this._determineDate(inst,this._get(inst, "defaultDate"), new Date()));
    }
```

to this....

```
_getDefaultDate: function(inst) {
    var def = this._get(inst, "defaultDate");
    return def !== null ? this._restrictMinMax(inst, this._determineDate(inst, def , new Date())): null;
},
```

2. The method *_setDate* was setting the selected day to the current day when null was passed into the date parameter. I changed to lines to correct this:

I changed this line...

```
inst.selectedDay = inst.currentDay = newDate.getDate();
```

to...

```
inst.selectedDay = date == null? 0: inst.currentDay = newDate.getDate();
```

and this line...

```
this._adjustInstDate(inst);
```

to...

```
if (date != null) {
    this._adjustInstDate(inst);
}
```

3. Lastly, the method *_generateHTML* did not handle a return value of null from *_getDefaultDate*.

So I changed this line...

```
    (defaultDate.getTime() === printDate.getTime() && defaultDate.getTime() === selectedDate.getTime()) ?
```

to...

```
(defaultDate != null && (defaultDate.getTime() === printDate.getTime() && defaultDate.getTime() === selectedDate.getTime())) ?
```

That's it. Now the *Datepicker* *defaultDate* option responds more intuitively to a value of *null* being passed in or to this option being missing.

```
$('#test').datepicker({ altField: '#alt'});  // No date selected
$('#test').datepicker({ altField: '#alt', defaultDate: null});  // No date selected
$('#test').datepicker({ altField: '#alt', defaultDate: 0});  // Today selected
$('#test').datepicker({ altField: '#alt', defaultDate: +1});  // Tomorrow selected
$('#test').datepicker({ altField: '#alt', defaultDate: -1});  // Yesterday selected
```

Here is a demo in *JSFIDDLE*: [Datepicker demo with defaultDate null](http://jsfiddle.net/s9fyh8c2/)

*Please note:* These changes have not been exhaustively tested, so there may be other issues arising from the fact that _getDefaultDate method now could return null. So do your own testing first! ;)

Hope this helps someone! :)

Comment: Thanks for the code! I also had to add `day = day || 1;` after `day = Math.min(inst.selectedDay, this._getDaysInMonth(year, month)) + (period === "D" ? offset : 0),` in the `_adjustInstDate` function so that clicking the arrow to change months would work on the first click. Otherwise the first click wouldn't change the month.

Comment: You are welcome; glad that it helped! And thanks also for the update.

Answer (score 6):

Based on the answers posted here, I managed to make something that worked.  For my purposes, I had an always visible calendar.  If you require this for a popup calendar, you should be able to use the existing `onSelect` handler to perform something similar the first time it's opened.

```
$("selector").datepicker(/* options */).find(".ui-state-active").removeClass("ui-state-active");
```

Thankfully, it's really that simple with the latest version of jQuery UI (1.10.2 as of this writing).  It doesn't appear to interfere with the correct functioning of the widget.  The only caveat is that using the `getDate` getter results in what would have normally been the default selected date.

For the purposes of my code, this is acceptable as my users cannot continue (they don't even have the continue button) until they've clicked on a valid date from the picker.  If this isn't the case for you, something like [Florian Peschka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668325/jquery-datepicker-no-default-date/3668459#3668459) should get you what you need.

Comment: Problem with this is when the calendar is redrawn. E.g. go to the next month, then go back to the current month, and "today" is hilighted as if it had been chosen. (Sorry, I don't have a solution to this.)

Comment: Well, you could probably do some finagling to make that work.  Given my use-case, I could simply check to see if the continue button is visible (i.e. the user has selected a date).  If it's not, I know it's still the default selected and can deselect it again.  I'm not certain exactly how I would hook the month switching code (probably on click of the next/prev buttons), but I don't think it would be impossible to pull off.

Comment: Yes, I found the `onChangeMonthYear` function shortly after posting the above, and use it: `onChangeMonthYear:function(year,month,inst){ if(no_choice_yet)setTimeout(function(){$("#datepicker .ui-state-active").removeClass("ui-state-active");},1);}`  (Strangely, I have no comment to explain why I wrapped it in `setTimeout`; but, even if not required, it does no harm.)

Comment: Darren cook > the triggers like onSelect and onChangeMonthYear trigger before the event beforeShowDay. So without setTimeout you remove it before it's actually drawn.

Answer (score 4):

To open the datepicker dialog it must be opened in some month of some year. I mean, you want to display this dialog and be blank?...

I think if you don't want to pass any default date, the best you can do is get the current date with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker();
});
```

Passing this will fail, because of given defaultDate, not null but blank

```
$(this).datepicker({defaultDate: ''});
```

This is something that will do what intended in the previous code

```
$(this).datepicker({defaultDate: null});
```

but it's behavior is the same as the first code block in this answer.

Comment: I certainly did. Did you read my comments before deleting them?

Comment: Did I? I didn't... @AaronMiller

Comment: I assumed you had, but fair enough; the gist was that forcing a default value makes form validation impossible to do with certainty, and that a better way to go about it would be to expose "show this month and year" and "set or clear the default value" capabilities separately in the datepicker API.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same probleme using **inline** datepicker.
The plugin add on today's cell/td the class .ui-datepicker-current-day and .ui-state-active. My solution is to use a custom class such as .ui-datepicker-selected-day and implements beforeShowDay to handle youself the display of the selected day. Something like that:

```
$("datepicker").datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
  var dateIso = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", date);
  var dateSelected = $("input").val();
  var classDate = "";
  if(dateSelected === dateIso){
    return [false,"ui-datepicker-selected-day"];
  }else{
    return [true];
  }
}
```

Sample of css to put in "highlight" the cell:

```
.ui-widget-content .ui-datepicker-selected-day .ui-state-active{
  background-color: red;
}
+ disable some css from the plugin
```

Answer (score 1):

I used `$('.datefield').val('')` to show blank instead of showing default date.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, and I found it because I had the same requirement; do not display a date in the input (textbox), make the user select a date from the datepicker.

**The Markup (MVC)**

```
<div class="leftContent">
     @Html.TextBox("DateShipOn", Nothing, New With {.class = "DateShipOn", .readonly = "readonly"})
</div>
```

**HTML Output:**

```
<div class="leftContent">
    <input id="DateShipOn" class="DateShipOn hasDatepicker" type="text" value="" readonly="readonly" name="DateShipOn">
</div>
```

**Script (in document ready):**

```
$('.DateShipOn').datepicker({
    constrainInput: true,
    display: true,
    border: true,
    background: true,
    maxDate: "+1m",
    minDate: new Date('@minDate')
});

$('.DateShipOn').datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

The effect of the above code is that the input box has the value of the 'minDate' variable in it on display AND when clicking on the input, the datepicker drops down and the 'minDate' is selected by default.

Note: We do not allow manual input, this is the reason for the 'readonly' attribute.

**Resolution:**

All I had to do, in my case, was comment/remove the line:

```
$('.DateShipOn').datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

**The Result:**

The effect is that on display;

- There is no default date value in the input (textbox)
- The user cannot type in the input (textbox)
- The date picker drops down with no default date selected
- The minDate prevents dates prior the minDate value from being selected
- The maxDate prevents dates after the maxDate value from being selected

Note: For my requirement the '+1m' for maxDate limits the date selection to only the 30 days from the minDate value.

Hope this helps someone out.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but with a specific behavior.

(As a side note, I think the expected behavior should be to start with the current date in the calendar, but *not* select it.)

My implementation included an inline calendar with a hidden input `altField`. What I did was remove the `altField` option, and add an `onSelect` function that updated it. This way the today date still looks selected, but the hidden field that represents the real value stays empty.

Answer (score 0):

My solution involves overriding jQuery's append so that we can remove the elements each time the HTML is regenerated and appended to the div. This fixes a flashing of the default date when switching months and it also clears the hover.

```
(function($) {
    var origAppend = $.fn.append;

    $.fn.append = function () {
        return origAppend.apply(this, arguments).trigger("append");
    };
})(jQuery);

var datePickerDiv = $("#date-picker");
datePickerDiv.bind("append", function() {
  $(this).find(".ui-datepicker-days-cell-over").removeClass("ui-datepicker-days-cell-over");
  $(this).find(".ui-datepicker-today a ").removeClass("ui-state-highlight ui-state-active ui-state-hover");
});

datePickerDiv.datepicker();
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker .ui-state-active").removeClass("ui-state-active");
    $("#datepicker .ui-state-highlight").removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
    $("#datepicker .ui-datepicker-today").removeClass("ui-datepicker-today");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put null value also like this:

```
  $(this).datepicker({defaultDate: null});
```

Answer (score -2):

What do you mean by wanting to "remove" the default date?

How do you think the datepicker will open up when he has no month to start from?! You **have** to have a default date.

**Edit on your comment**

Set a default date as you want and check, if the user has changed it. If so, he selected a custom date.

Another approach would be to create a variable that is set to `true` as soon as the user clicks on the datepicker field.

If the user submits the form, you check for that variable. If it's `true`, the user has selected a date. If not, he didn't touch the datepicker field.

Comment: What I mean is, of course, that I dont want a selected date when the datepicker opens up. In my site, I want to make it mandatory for the user to make a choice before he can continue.

Comment: It will open up with no date selected if set up correctly.

user352985 - see my answer I posted, it can be done and it can be done rather easily actually.

Comment: I downvoted this because there seems to be an automatic assumption that today's date should be selected by default. If you're using the calendar as the basis for any kind of booking system, that is extremely unhelpful - my customers need to be able to select their own dates. The datepicker functionality is essentially broken. If the date is unset internally (using the approved method, as documented in the API) then the date shouldn't still be highlighted on the calendar afterwards. There's no reason why any date should be selected on the calendar by default, that's just how it's configured.

Comment: @NoelWhitemore What I mean by "You have to have a default date" is that you need to show something when opening the picker, right? What month/year would you show without a default date? How could you decide what to show if not with a default date? Maybe it shouldn't be selected, but just decide which month/year to show, but you still need something to start with!

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean now :) It is fine to set the calendar view to the current month (most users would expect this) but I do not think it is appropriate for today's date to be automatically selected, as if the user had already clicked on the calendar themselves. The problem I have with the datepicker widget is that when I use the API to unselect the default date, the date is still highlighted on the calendar even though (internally) the date has been unset. The only way to fix this seems to be by manually removing the CSS styles or hacking the jQuery UI code.

Comment: Yes, we agree on that. There should be two separate settings. "Selected Date" and "Initial month/year" or something.