# jquery datepicker disable default today select

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using jquery datepicker this is my code

```
jQuery( "#calenderonem3" ).datepicker({

    firstDay: 1,

    showOtherMonths: true,

    numberOfMonths: 1,

    altField: "#InputDat",

    altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",

    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',


});
```

Now using this code calender is displayed and it also make today date is selected default and highlighted.
I want to disable this default selection, how can I do that?

I also have tried this one but not working.
 [default date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668325/jquery-datepicker-no-default-date)

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery Datepicker - no default date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668325/jquery-datepicker-no-default-date)

Comment: I have tried that answer but not working