# Default date for jQuery UI datapicker

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I have set up a jQuery UI inline datapicker and has disallowed the present and previous dates. This automatically selects tomorrow as the default date. However, I would like to not have a date selected by default.
How can I accomplish this?

```
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            inline: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            minDate: 1,
            defaultDate: ???,
        });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mckeene/pe05vjcy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it would seem it takes a bit to get it to default to nothing.  Expanding on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28078137/99401 I ended up with this:

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  inline: true,
  firstDay: 1,
  minDate: 1,
  setDate: null
});
$("#datepicker").find(".ui-datepicker-current-day a").removeClass("ui-state-active");
$("#datepicker").find(".ui-datepicker-current-day a").removeClass("ui-datepicker-days-cell-over");
$("#datepicker").find(".ui-datepicker-current-day a").removeClass("ui-state-hover");
```

See here for an updated working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/jreljac/rdnk9yk2/3/

Comment: Hi Jason. Here is how it looks like https://jsfiddle.net/mckeene/pe05vjcy/

Comment: Thank you very much. Weird that it is not part of the default options.