# default date in jquery UI datepicker

Tags: php, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using jquery UI datepicker in php for appointment calendar, in which some days are disable like holidays. I want to avoid default selected value of datepicker if this date is in holidays list, because if user click on submit button without selecting any date the default today's date will insert into database. 
my code to show datepicker in form is:

```
<div class="datepicker custom_datepicker" id="calendar" ></div>
```

Is there any way to avoid default date in Jquery UI datepicker?

Comment: provide your code.

Answer (score 0):

The defaultDate options can help you.
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate

That can be a number, string or dateObject
    defaultDate: +7
    defaultDate: new Date(1985, 00, 01)

So in PHP, just compare the today date with your holiday date's list et if need change the default Date.

But to disabled the defaultDate, try this : [JQuery Datepicker - no default date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668325/jquery-datepicker-no-default-date)